# Unable to create classes dynamically using mixin inside each

Tags: css, sass

I have a map variable i.e. `$breakpoints`. I use it for `@mixin mediaQuery`. The mixin works pretty well wherever I have used it however I'm unable to generate classes dynamically when using this map variable `$breakpoints` inside a `@each` which further uses `@mixin mediaQuery` which further uses `$breakpoints`.

I do not know if this way of using the map variable is the reason why my `@each` is not generating classes. Need help in fixing this!

```
$breakpoints: (
    Phone: 400px,
    PhoneWide: 480px,
    Phablet: 560px,
    TabletSmall: 640px,
    Tablet: 768px,
    TabletWide: 1024px,
    Desktop: 1248px,
    DesktopWide: 1440px
);

@mixin mediaQuery($width, $type: min) {
    @if map_has_key($breakpoints, $width) {
        $width: map_get($breakpoints, $width);
        @if $type == max {
            $width: $width - 1px;
        }
        @media only screen and (#{$type}-width: $width) {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@each $name, $value in $breakpoints {
    // This part does not work
    .beHide#{$name} {
        @include mediaQuery($value) {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong argument to the mixin.

Instead of passing `$value` you should: `@include mediaQuery($name)`.

Comment: Ohh man! That's a silly mistake i've been trying to figure out. I'll check and would let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes we are so focused on one thing that we don't see the obvious. ;)